Understanding noise in analog circuit
I have been wondering in this analog circuit when we try to find out the input referred noise, how I went about is, I first found out the output referred noise power spectral density. I modelled a floating current source between the drain and source of the NMOS for noise due to the NMOS and two separate noise current sources between two terminals of Rd and Rs respectively. My question is when I am finding out the noise at the output, I am pretty sure the noise due to Rd will add up, but I am doubtful about the noise component due to Rs.

Clarification, I'll reach to input referred noise by dividing the output noise by gain squared...

Prabhjit Singh - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, public & legal, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in [tour] & [help].)

The noise from RD will appear directly at the output, as RD is connected between VDD and Vout. The thermal noise voltage of RD (typically modeled as 4kTRD in terms of power spectral density) will directly add to the output noise without any attenuation or transformation.
The noise from RS, however, is a bit more complex. Since RS is connected to the source of the NMOS transistor M1, it affects the output noise through feedback. The noise voltage generated by RS will be “seen” at the source of M1 and will be multiplied by the gain from the source to the output (which depends on the transconductance gm of M1 and the impedances in the circuit).
Typically, the noise from RS does not add directly to the output like RD's noise does. Instead, it influences the output through a feedback mechanism and gets multiplied by a factor that involves the transconductance gm and the impedance at the drain (which includes RD).
You also need to consider the channel thermal noise of the transistor M1, which is usually modeled as a noise current source between the drain and source. This noise current, when flowing through RD, will produce a noise voltage at the output.
To address your main question about whether the noise due to RS adds directly at the output:
It doesn’t add linearly at the output like RD does. Instead, the noise contribution from  appears at the output after being modulated by the circuit’s gain. The exact contribution of RS’s noise to the output noise depends on the small-signal parameters of the transistor M1 (particularly gm) and the interaction with the impedance at the source node. This can be represented by a gain factor, which will typically reduce the direct effect of RS's noise at the output relative to RD's noise.
